# MPAndroidChart y-axis grid lines are messed up. How to arrange properly?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my project. And I experiencing some troubles with Y axis lines.
Here it is my code:

```
    chart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    entries.add(new Entry(1, 0));
    entries.add(new Entry(6, 15));
    entries.add(new Entry(7, 9));
    entries.add(new Entry(15, 90));

    chart.setDescription("");

    YAxis yRight  =  chart.getAxisRight();
    YAxis yLeft  =  chart.getAxisLeft();
    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();

    yRight.setDrawLabels(false);
    yRight.setDrawAxisLine(false);

    //chart.setVisibleYRange(0, 100, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    yLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    yLeft.setDrawGridLines(true);
    yLeft.setAxisMaxValue(100f);
    yLeft.setAxisMinValue(0f);
    yLeft.setLabelCount(5, true);
    yLeft.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#414345"));

    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#414345"));

    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Label");
    dataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5dd054"));
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.parseColor("#313234"));
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);

    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
    chart.setData(lineData);
    chart.invalidate();
```

if I set `yLeft.setDrawGridLines(true)` to `true` it appears like this:

[image]

if I set `yLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)` to `false` it appears like this:

[image]

In both ways lines are messed up. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The axis lines of the right axis interfere with your chart. Try this:

```
 XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
 xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
 xl.setDrawGridLines(false);

 YAxis yl = chart.getAxisLeft();
 yl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
 yl.setDrawGridLines(false);

 YAxis yr = chart.getAxisRight();
 yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
 yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Comment: Thank you I decided to make my own chart.

Comment: Good choice, mpchart sucks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to override the following attributes:

```
xAxis.gridColor
xAxis.axisLineColor
xAxis.axisLineWidth
xAxis.gridLineWidth
```